# Need to identify this 'appearing before compilation' dialog in my Delphi xe4 IDE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, delphi-ide

I want to disable the dialog (shown below, titled "Processing File") appears each time I compile or build my project, but I failed to find which IDE plugins it's from since I use a lot of productivity plugins (also shown below).

Anybody has any hint :P

[image]

The List of IDE plugins I use is shown below - PS, I believe the DKLang is not shown there.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "I believe the DKLang is not shown there."  You can see that it is not shown, so you must mean something else, but what?

Comment: The other thing is that your screen-shot shows that you are obviously using GExperts' ExpertManager and have disabled the Beyond Compare one.  Why didn't you say what happens when you disable all the others instead of leaving readers to guess?

Comment: Why get winform spy tool (many free ones available) to see what the form's name is. This could give you a clue what it is from.

Comment: That list of plug-ins are only the .bpl plug-ins and not .dll plug-ins.

Comment: @NicholasRing:  Typo?  All the ones listed on my system have a .Dll extension.

Comment: @MartynA I remember I tried checking by disabling the experts one by one few months ago, but I'm not sure, so I'll try that again. Re. your question - there are two kinds of IDE experts and the GExperts Expert Manager only list one kind of them, as said by Nicholas.

Comment: @NicholasRing the dialog appears and disappear after about one second so I don't have time for the window spy tool.

Comment: @FreeConsulting, thanks, while the problem has been fixed, I'd like to learn how to pause the the Delphi IDE/compiler process. Thanks. Re. the **usefulness*, well, while it's not a programming question, it's still a question about the IDE where you programming in. And GExperts is a Delphi plugin widely in use, I guess it might be useful when someone is in situation like I was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted by Andy Vines the Delphi G+ group user, that's because I somehow have enabled the 'Set Component Properties' expert included in the GExperts IDE plugin.

It searches for and auto-close active database connections, datasets, etc.

Disabling it fixed the problem. Thanks.